# How to open Youtube app main activity

Tags: android

I am trying to open the MainActivity of YouTube app using the code below.

```
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
             intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that the code above work fine when the Youtube app is updated to last version, but fail when the user have an old version of Youtube.

How can I open the YouTube main activity without to care what version the user have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
Intent i = app.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
if (i != null) 
    app.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Cool, it opens youtube, but how to force it to open the give film or the given channel?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple intent having ACTION_VIEW :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("your_youtube_link"));
startActivity(intent)
```

If your link is a youtube link, the native chooser should ask you what application you want to use : one of your browsers, or the youtube application if available.

Comment: I don't need to open the player activity, I need just to open the mainActivity for search action, so the browser is not useful for me as on of my activity is shared for incoming intent for Youtube links.

Comment: Your answer is not the exact one the asker needed but I think this is the better way to do it since it is not guaranteed that the user will have youtube installed.